# Android account manager with private API

Tags: android, accountmanager

For a school project i require authentication within android app.
We would like to simplify the login procedure using Android account manager, so the user only have to authenticate once.

our API is hosted is at http://projectpep.herokuapp.com/users/login.
on a successful login (using POST username: test, password:test) you get the token.

I followed certain demos, like [this tutorial](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/), however i cannot find out how to let it make use of our own API.

How can i use my own api in combination with account manager?